# C# converting int to hex

Tags: c#

This is a small snippet of the code I have written in Visual Studio.
I need to convert the int `add` into an hex value (later into a string) as I am accessing the memory of a uC. But when I view the variable during debugging it displays it as a string "add16". What could I be doing wrong?

```
for (int add = 0; add <= 0xfffff; )
{
    for (int X = 0; X <= 15; X++)
    {
        string address = add.ToString("add16");
        addr = Convert.ToString(address);
        port.WriteLine(String.Format("WRBK:{0}:{1}", addr, parts[X]));
        add++;
    } 
}
```

Comment: The other answers here will all work, but I would suggest looking through the [numeric format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#XFormatString) to understand why your way doesn't work. You can use `ToString()` to get a hexadecimal string from an int, but you have to pass in the right format string, e.g. `add.ToString("X")`.

Comment: I would point out that you cannot "convert an int to hex", you can only convert it to a hex string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple and very convenient method that takes an integer and returns a representation of it as a string in hexadecimal notation

```
string address = Convert.ToString(add, 16);
```

So, perhaps, your internal loop could be rewritten as

```
port.WriteLine(String.Format("WRBK:{0}:{1}", Convert.ToString(add++, 16), parts[X]));
```

and using the [standard numeric format strings specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) reduced to

```
port.WriteLine(String.Format("WRBK:{0:X}:{1}", add++, parts[X]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can tell .NET's `String.Format`  to use hex output for the integer, eliminating any code to hex conversion, use:

```
port.WriteLine(String.Format("WRBK:{0:X}:{1}", add, parts[X]));
```